# Display hamburger menu only on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, frontend

I have created a hamburger menu in react it displays content on breakpoint as expected. But can any body help me to display the hamburger menu icon only on breakpoint otherwise it should display the Navigation menu?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could use a third-party library like [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) and then conditionally render the hamburger menu when a certain device width condition is met. For example, let's say you want to show the `<HamburgerMenu />` component when the device with is less than `500px`. You could use something like this:

```
// after installing react-responsive and assuming you have a separate HamburgerMenu and DesktopMenu component
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';
import DesktopMenu from './DesktopMenu';
import HamburgerMenu from './Hamburger';

const NavigationMenu = () => {
 const isMobile = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(max-width: 500px)',
  });
 
 return {isMobile ? <HamburgerMenu /> : <DesktopMenu />}

}
```

---- UPDATE ----

---

Since you mentioned you don't want to use any third-party libraries, I will add a custom functionality to render components based on `window` object's innerWidth.

I added a `getWindowSize()` function that will get the `window.innerWidth`. Then I will run this function after the page is rendered for the first time using `useEffect` hook and update the `windowsize` state. I will also add a `resize` event to `window` object to run this function if the window object is being resized. Then based on the `windowsize` state I will conditionally render what I want (in my example I used `500px` as an example. Please see it here:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Hamburger from './Hamburger';
import DesktopMenu from './DesktopMenu';

export default function App() {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getWindowSize());

  function getWindowSize() {
    const { innerWidth } = window;
    return { innerWidth };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleWindowResize() {
      setWindowSize(getWindowSize());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Width: {windowSize.innerWidth}</h2>
      {windowSize.innerWidth < 500 ? <Hamburger /> : <DesktopMenu />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not using any third party libraries. Could you please suggest some without any libraries.

Comment: It's not that hard to implement it without using third-party libraries. I will update my response to include a custom built functionality to render different components based on different device widths.